Power Automate Paging with FetchXML
We have a case where we need to fetch more than 5,000 records from a D365 entity. We cannot use OData filtering due to complexity of the query, so we have to use FetchXML.
In the screenshot below, all records (there are about 5,300) are fetched successfully using paging mechanism. Note, there's no action under Apply To Each which of course is unrealistic.

However, when we add ANY action under Apply To Each (even a simple Compose action which doesn't even use any data and just composes a static hard coded value, the paging stops working and Do Until only fires once instead of 2-3 times as it does without Compose action.

This is extremely strange and we cannot find any reasonable explanation to this behavior. Has anyone come across something similar and how did you overcome it?
TIA,
Tony S.

Not sure why you are getting this issue. But I would be interested to hear why you want to use the apply to each in the do until? You want manipulate the incomplete data while it is still fetching it in the do until loop. Can explain the reason/requirement why you want loop through the results before it is done fetching the results in your Do Until? Normally I would say place the apply to each logic outside of the do until loop?

If you use FetchXML all other properties (paging, filters, selects, etc.) are ignored
